# Evaluating a parameter pack

Tags: c++, templates, c++17, variadic-templates, fold-expression

Is this the only way to evaluate a parameter pack without using folding (since it requires the use of operators)?

```cpp
#include <iostream>

template<int ...Is, typename Function>
void eval(Function&& f)
{
    // (f(Is)...);
    auto op = [&f](int i){f(i); return 0;};
    auto doNothing = [](auto...){};
    doNothing(op(Is)...);
}

int main()
{
    eval<0,1,2>([](int x){std::cout << x << "\n";});
}
```

Essentially I want to do `(f(Is)...)`, but for some reason, this is disallowed in C++. Is there a more elegant way this can be achieved than by using the workaround presented above?

Comment: @user7769147 that's not true, this is just fine.

Comment: never underestimate the power of the comma operator

Comment: You just need a coma between `f(Is)` and `...`. `(f(Is)...)` is a parameter pack expansion that can appear as a function argument. `(f(Is),...)` is a fold expression on the comma operator.

Comment: `since it requires the use of operators`: coma is an operator!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There is a simpler solution:

```
#include <iostream>

template<int ...Is, typename Function>
void eval(Function&& f)
{
    (f(Is),...);
}

int main()
{
    eval<0,1,2>([](int x){std::cout << x << "\n";});
}
```

Comment: What happens if someone overloads `,` though?

Comment: @lightxbulb: you fire them :) `((void)f(Is),...)` might prevent the overload, or something like that.